# How to delete a chatroom from openfire in PHP

Tags: php, rest, openfire

I have created a chatroom from openfire know i have to delete a chatroom
from openfire.for this i have using REST api plugin with the help of curl.
I have tried below code but it is not working for this i have also refer the
docs from REST api plugin of openfire but i am not getting where i am going wrong please guide me to resolve this issue.

Code using REST API plugin to delete a chatroom

```
<?php

        $url1 = "http://ipaddress:9090/plugins/restapi/v1/chatrooms";

        $data1 = "<chatroom>
    <roomname>test</roomname>
    <servicename>conference</servicename>
    </chatroom>";

        $username1 = "Adminconsoleusername";
        $password1 = "Adminconsolepassword";
        $ch1 = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_URL, $url1);
        curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_PORT, "9090");
        curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data1);
        curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);
        curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/xml', 'Authorization: Basic ' . base64_encode("$username1:$password1")));
        $code1 = curl_getinfo($ch1, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
        curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        //echo $code1;
        $res1 = curl_exec($ch1);
        //echo "code " . $code;
        echo $res1;
        print_r($res1);

        curl_close($ch1);
```

I have also refer the REST api doc
https://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/openfire/plugins/restapi/readme.html#examples-20

Please help me,
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

The URL should also contain the chat room you like to delete. 
e.g $url1 = "http://ipaddress:9090/plugins/restapi/v1/chatrooms/testroom";